# Listview Selector

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a State List Drawable xml

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_pressed" />
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_disabled" />
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Whenever I select the row in the listview I want it to show my pressed image and then when it releases it shows the transparent background (normal). However, it always shows my disabled image after releasing. I need to have the disabled image whenever I disable a row (grey). Any ideas what i'm doing wrong? Also, is there a way to capture the different states (focused, pressed, enabled) to have a better idea what is happening behind the scenes, this might help me in understanding what is happening?

Comment: can we see the statelistdrawable xml

Comment: Maybe your views are already disabled?

Comment: try adding `state_enable` to your state list

Answer (score 1):

[This example](http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2009/12/android-selectors.html) should be a good help.

Here's how XML should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/listitem_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/listitem_selected" />
</selector>
```